# Flutter load data from a list class object to a DropdownMenuItem using map

Tags: flutter

I have been able to load items from a List class object into a DropdownButton but wanted to know how to achieve the same if the data in a separate file.

I have the below files which can be accessed on https://github.com/jsingh-github/flutterlistview

1. main.dart
2. list_currency: renders the view
3. coin_class:defines the coin list class
4. data: contains the currency list

**Query: in the below list_currency file, the second container has a child widget dropdownbutton. how do populate the dropdownbutton by initialising  currencieslist object and then with the data from the data file.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:listprint/coin_class.dart';

class ListCurrency extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListCurrencyState createState() => _ListCurrencyState();
}

class _ListCurrencyState extends State<ListCurrency> {
  String selectedCurrency = 'USD';
  CoinData coinData = CoinData();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List View'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 400,
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Center(
              child: FlatButton(
                child: Text('Print List'),
                onPressed: () {
                  print(coinData.currenciesList);
                },
                color: Colors.deepOrange,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 150.0,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              value: selectedCurrency,
            items: coinData.currenciesList.map((currencyitem) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text(currencyitem),
                  value: currencyitem,
              );
            }).toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedCurrency = value;
                  print(selectedCurrency);
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is the solution to convert the list data in the data file to a function as below and then call the function from the list_currency?

```
  List<String> getCurrencies ( ) {
  
  const currencies = [
    'AUD',
    'BRL',
    'CAD',
    'CNY',
    'EUR',
    'GBP',
    'HKD',
    'IDR',
    'ILS',
    'INR',
    'JPY',
    'MXN',
    'NOK',
    'NZD',
    'PLN',
    'RON',
    'RUB',
    'SEK',
    'SGD',
    'USD',
    'ZAR'
  ]; 
  
  return currencies; 

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and adding additionnal information in it!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the values from a list to a dropdown as below

```
    DropdownButton<String> androidDropdown() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [];
    for (String currency in currenciesList) {
      var newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(currency),
        value: currency,
      );
      dropdownItems.add(newItem);
    }

    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: selectedCurrency,
      items: dropdownItems,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          selectedCurrency = value;
          //2: Call getData() when the picker/dropdown changes.
          getData();
        });
      },
    );
  }

String bitcoinValue = '?';

  void getData() async {
    try {
      //We're now passing the selectedCurrency when we call getCoinData().
      var data = await CoinData().getCoinData(selectedCurrency);
      setState(() {
        bitcoinValue = data;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```